# How much do SpaceX's titanium grid fin geometrical parameters measure?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, grid-fins

Does anyone know approximately what is the width, length, thickness and depth of the titanium grid fins used in the Falcon9 v1.1?

I'm trying to make a 3D model on solidworks but can't find the figures anywhere,

Thanks

Comment: To give you a ballpark answer, a Queen-sized bed mattress is similar.